# python post with requests

Tags: python, post, request

i have next request which has been captured with firebug, i want to re-use this request. This POST request happen when i press "Submit" button, somebody can help me please adjust this request for python requests library.

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Content-Length  5419
Content-Type    text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8
Cookie  JSESSIONID=0000nJNqFPHEWvBoven6ubi8c2E:17oe8njmt;
SessionTimeoutTimer=1424436529792; resourceLoadStart=1424436528864; wdp-initial-auth=false; 
LtpaToken2=mytoken
DNT 1
Host    myhost.com
Pragma  no-cache
Referer http://myhost/webapp/1/
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
X-GWT-Module-Base   http://myhostcom/webapp/1/
X-GWT-Perf-result   [{"moduleName":"com.my.module", "subSystem":"startup", "eventGroup":"moduleStartup", "millis":1424436529193, "type":"moduleEvalEnd", "parameters":{"sessionId":"", "windowId":"70489170848"}},{"moduleName":"com.my.module", "subSystem":"startup", "eventGroup":"moduleStartup", "millis":1424436529194, "type":"onModuleLoadStart", "parameters":{"sessionId":"", "className":"com.google.gwt.useragent.client.UserAgentAsserter", "windowId":"70489170848"}}]
X-GWT-Perf-uid  4
X-GWT-Perf-wnd-id   70489170848
X-GWT-Permutation   548AB49A6680866C6B602849711C2FAC
```

My code looks like that:

```
cookies = {
'JSESSIONID': 'sessionID',
'SessionTimeoutTimer': '1424432784218',
'resourceLoadStart': '1424432777757',
'wdp-initial-auth': 'false',
'LtpaToken2': 'mytoken',
 }


headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Content-Length': '5415',
'Content-Type': 'text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8',
'DNT': '1',
'Host': 'http://myweb/webapp/1/',
'Pragma': 'no-cache',
'Referer': 'http://myweb/webapp/1/',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0',
'X-GWT-Module-Base': 'http://myweb/webapp/1/',
'X-GWT-Perf-result': '[{"moduleName":"com.myweb.webapp.1", "subSystem":"rpc", "eventGroup":"6", "millis":1424432798282, "type":"begin", "parameters":{"sessionId":"", "method":"CommandDispatcher_Proxy.execute", "windowId":"766855627216"}},{"moduleName":"com.myweb.webapp.1", "subSystem":"rpc", "eventGroup":"6", "millis":1424432798315, "type":"requestSerialized", "parameters":{"sessionId":"", "method":"CommandDispatcher_Proxy.execute", "windowId":"766855627216"}}]',
'X-GWT-Perf-uid': '6',
'X-GWT-Perf-wnd-id': '766855627216',
'X-GWT-Permutation': '548AB49A6680866C6B602849711C2FAC',
}


data = {
"moduleName":"my.module.1", "subSystem":"rpc", "eventGroup":"6",        "type":"begin", "parameters":{"sessionId":"",   "method":"CommandDispatcher_Proxy.execute",}},{"moduleName":"my.module.1", "subSystem":"rpc", "eventGroup":"6",  "type":"requestSerialized", "parameters":{"sessionId":"", "method":"CommandDispatcher_Proxy.execute", }}
 data = json.dumps(data)

with requests.session() as c:
    url = 'http://myweb/webapp/1/gwt.base.client.command.CommandDispatcher.rpc'

    c.post(url, headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)

print c
```

Comment: it appears your indentation is a bit off, since when you print c it doesn't exist. Also, you have two brackets behind the data initialization when you only need one.